# Ubuntu Postgres started refusing connections

Tags: linux, postgresql

A Postgres instance on Ubuntu started refusing connections from PgAdmin.  A restart of the instance and service resulted in no listener running on port 5432.

- The log had a startup error that postmaster.pid lockfile could not be removed, access denied.
- The postmaster.pid file on my system is at /mnt/pgdata/postgresql/11/main.  I enabled access to it with permissions "u+w".  It seemed weird to do this.
- So then the service started up with an error

  FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
  DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres"
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 87: "local all postgres md5"
- At this point I can use psql locally, but remote connection attempts from PgAdmin result in

  FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "x.x.x.X", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "X.X.X.X", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

What happened, and how do I fix it?  Neither changing the OS postgres password or the Postgreql user password had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This all relates, somehow, to a "pgdbadm" attack.  Erased remnants of it, and am looking to better secure the system.